# get a single Boolean value from set in R

Tags: r, boolean

```
U= runif(5)
head=U[U<0.5]
U[1:5] == head
```

If I run third row in this code, I obviously get FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE.
(It might be different in other seed of computer.)
What I want to get is a single Boolean value that indicates that whether all value of U is head or not.
In other word, if all element of U is head, my expected value is TRUE.
If any element of U is not head, than I want FALSE to be printed.

Comment: `all(U[1:5] == head)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
U= runif(5)

 all(U<.5)
#[1] FALSE
```

In your version the length of `head` is likely to be less than 5 so assigning it to U[1:5] Is likely to lead to confusion or error.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder it is impossible to compare two different sized set with {all} function.

Comment: I'm not sure what is desired. The action that was not making sense was the assignment operation using a fixed index vector.